# Teamcity checkout rules analogue in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, teamcity, git-checkout

We're migrating from TeamCity to Jenkins and I got a task to transfer all the VCS roots from TC to Jenkins taking into account checkout rules.

How could I do that? Is there an analogue in Jenkins?

Many thanks!